# Custom Google search shortcuts for link navigation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, minify

I recently changed back from duckduckgo to Google search. And one feature I miss a lot is J and K navigation keys. So first I was using this Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jk-shortcuts-navigator/chgfodomgimhbcmlfljhkgildehakgif?hl=en

But I also decided a few months ago to switch my keyboard layout to a bépo ergonomic layout (Dvorak adapted to French typing). So my <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> position are now replaced by <kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>. And of course, the Chrome extension above does not allow to change the shortcuts.

So I had the idea about creating my own extension to allow to use custom shortcuts for up/down navigation in google results.

I was thinking about finding which function google calls in Javascript when the user types "up" or "down" and add my custom script calling those same function when a custom shortcut is hit. But as the code is minified, it is hard to find out (even with knowing "up" and "down" keycodes or using chrome developer tools with "event listener breakpoints" in the script panel).

Secondly I noticed this little arrow next to a selected search item in Google search. It is a span located just after the div result. But moving this span manually does not change the selected link so I can't hit enter to navigate to it.

Do you have an idea of how I can do this ?
Google is handling this pretty well with scroll support and so on. That is why I wanted to use their functions…

But maybe it is too complicated and I would better develop my own custom extension ?

Comment: You can't use page's javascript function easily from an injected content script because of the sandboxed execution environement. Content Script are not allowed to use the original page's javascript content and the original page's javascript is not allowed to use your Content Script's javascript content. It's not as simple as that, you can bypass this restriction because you're sharing the same DOM but it will not be esthetic...

Comment: So in other words you say I should develop my own extension? I thought that extensions could "extend" websites behaviors by interacting with them so that is why I wanted to do that. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Hum no :-) What I m trying to say is that it will be dificult to "extend" an existing behavior. I have a pretty bad english excuse me :-)

Comment: Not a pb ;). One solution I have by now is tweacking the extension "jk-navigator" changing "j" and "k" to "t" and "s" because I found the code on github so I can load it as an unpacked module: https://github.com/skalnik/jk-navigator

Comment: This will work and is pretty simple ;-) And you can make a demand to the developpper to make a configuration page ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That extension you found is open source. You can find it here: https://github.com/flavio87/jk-navigator

You can change j and k by modifying the source and following the Manual installation instructions. The line you want to change is here:
https://github.com/flavio87/jk-navigator/blob/master/jk-shortcuts-navigator/script.js#L151